# switch string with accent not matching

Tags: r, encoding, switch-statement

I'm having trouble with a switch statement that is supposed to match a character with accent. The character string I want to match comes from a vector (data$ttx), himself coming from an excel sheet read with openxlsx.

```
> head(data$ttx)
[1] "Autorisé" "Autorisé" "Autorisé" "Autorisé" "Interdit" "Autorisé"
```

Here is the reproduction of my problem :

```
> x = data$ttx[1]
> switch(x, "oui" =, "Autorisé" = TRUE, "non" =, "Interdit" = FALSE, x)
#this doesn't work, it returns "Autorisé", the default statement
```

But if I do :

```
> x = "Autorisé"
> switch(x, "oui" =, "Autorisé" = TRUE, "non" =, "Interdit" = FALSE, x)
#this works, it returns TRUE
```

I'm guessing it is because of the accent in the string because for the other cases ("oui", "non", "Interdit") it works fine. My guess would be that the extraction from excel has given an invisible difference between the character strings in my vector, compared to strings written directly in R. The problem seems to be quite specific to the switch function because if I try :

```
> data$ttx[1] == "Autorisé"
#this returns TRUE
```

Do you know of this issue ? Do you have a way around it ?

EDIT : More informations :

```
> dput(head(data$ttx))
c("Autorisé", "Autorisé", "Autorisé", "Autorisé", "Interdit", "Autorisé")
> Encoding(head(data$ttx))
[1] "UTF-8"   "UTF-8"   "UTF-8"   "UTF-8"   "unknown" "UTF-8"
```

Comment: You may need `lapply/sapply` i.e. `lapply(x, function(y) switch(y, "oui" =, "Autorisé" = TRUE, "non" =, "Interdit" = FALSE, y ))`  According to `?swtich` `EXPR - an expression evaluating to a number or a character string.`

Comment: you will need to give us the exact structure of your data (`dput(data$ttx)`) because it must be an encoding issue, as it is stated, it can not be reproduced: `x <- "Autorisé" ; switch(x, "oui" =, "Autorisé" = TRUE, "non" =, "Interdit" = FALSE, x)`=> `[1] TRUE`

Comment: That's actually exactly what I'm doing : `data$ttx[!is.na(data$ttx)] = sapply(data$ttx[!is.na(data$ttx)], function(x){switch(x, "oui" =,"Autorisé" = TRUE, "non" =,"Interdit" = FALSE,  x)})` I just tried to simplify the question. But the problem remains ...

Comment: by the way, why using `switch` rather than `data$ttx %in% c("oui", "Autorisé")` which can be applied on the whole `vector`, contrary to `switch` which is not vectorised

Comment: It was a way to do everything in one statement and avoid a conversion to character, but you're right, it can be done in 3 statements as `data$ttx[data$ttx %in% c("oui","Autorisé")] = TRUE`, `data$ttx[data$ttx %in% c("non","Interdit")] = FALSE` and `data$ttx = as.logical(data$ttx)`

Comment: @Yvonnig just `data$ttx <- data$ttx %in% c("oui","Autorisé")` will do what you want in a single statement ;-)

Comment: That's actually true, I didn't thought about that ! Thanks !